#1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
Issue:
When using PHPmyAdmin version 5.2.1 tools to edit or insert a geometry object it throws error: #1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field.
This issue was reproducible in PHPmyAdmin version 5.2.1 but not reproducible in version of 5.1.3.
Specifically, when I use the internal tool to manually input the Lat and lng values it generates the SQL query below which inserts escape characters(') into the query sting.
UPDATE `allpages_geodata` SET `geoData` = ST_GeomFromText('\'POINT(2.9501061323936 42.27264217835078)\',0') WHERE `allpages_geodata`.`pageId` = 'a0205'

I also tried swapping around the lat and lng in the tool and multiple browsers(cache cleared) and it still throws the same error.
Note that pasting 'POINT(2.9501061323936106 42.27264217835078)',0 into the value column where it is set to ST_GeomFromText throws the same error when I select go to run the query because this version of PHPmyAdmin builds the SQL query incorrectly with escape characters from the GUI.



Workaround:
My only workaround was to manually create the SQL query and run it in the phpMyadmin SQL tab or from a PHP script.
UPDATE `allpages_geodata` SET `geoData` = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2.9501061323936106 42.27264217835078),0') WHERE `allpages_geodata`.`pageId` = 'a0205';


This is a PHPmyadmin bug specifiic to version of 5.1.3 whereby when you use the inbuilt GUI tool to define the geometry POINT it builds the SQL query incorrectly.
My reason for posting this is if anyone else gets stuck and is forced to use PHPmyAdmin version of 5.1.3 by their shared hosting provider.
Hopefully this will save someone else 3 hours of troubleshooting.

My reason for manipulating Geometry data using the inbuilt PHPmyAdmin tool was that when I imported an SQL table (downloaded as sql) from phpMyAdmin version 5.1.3 database into PHPmyAdmin 5.2.1 database it threw an error and did not upload the table data. I was only able to upload the table as a CSV but with some geometry POINTS with corrupted coords and therefore needed to manually adjust a few.
